# Why some package can import a module that does *not* exist in the folder that it means to import from?

Tags: python, import, package, code-maintainability

When I try to look at the implementation of some `numpy` functions, I realized a strange thing (description below).

In this python script: `/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py`

Inside this file: `from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import *`

However, when I go to the folder to check, I also use terminal to `ls` all files under the that folder `/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core`, the `_multiarray_umath` is not included in any of the file under that folder, as shown below:

```
__init__.py
__pycache__
_add_newdocs.py
_aliased_types.py
_asarray.py
_dtype.py
_dtype_ctypes.py
_dummy.cpython-37m-darwin.so
_exceptions.py
_internal.py
_methods.py
_multiarray_tests.cpython-37m-darwin.so
_multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-darwin.so
_operand_flag_tests.cpython-37m-darwin.so
_rational_tests.cpython-37m-darwin.so
_string_helpers.py
_struct_ufunc_tests.cpython-37m-darwin.so
_type_aliases.py
_ufunc_config.py
_umath_tests.cpython-37m-darwin.so
arrayprint.py
cversions.py
defchararray.py
einsumfunc.py
fromnumeric.py
function_base.py
generate_numpy_api.py
getlimits.py
include
info.py
lib
machar.py
memmap.py
multiarray.py
numeric.py
numerictypes.py
overrides.py
records.py
setup.py
setup_common.py
shape_base.py
tests
umath.py
umath_tests.py
```

I'm really confused how such mechanism works? Can you please explain it with plain English and also point me to some resources that I can learn the motivation behind all such package development practice?

Comment: ?? It is in your list: `_multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-darwin.so`

Comment: It because some of `numpy` is implemented in C — which is why it is so fast — and provided as dynamic `.so` library files.

Comment: @Nic3500 Okay, you might see the question we actually have is that can we import any `.so` module in the folder by ignoring whatever appendix after the module name, like ignoring `.cpython-37m-darwin.so`?

Comment: One thing you could do to test it is rename the file (keep it!).  If you have import errors, you will know that it was indeed that file that was imported.  Then put it back.